# Update a record & return ID of the updated record in C# & SQL

Tags: c#, sql, ado, sqlparameter

I have written a code to insert a row and return inserted row id to the calling point of that function. Now I need to write a code to update a record & need to get the Id of updated record.

How to do it in C#? looking for a same way as insertion method without using output parameters.

My insert method as follows:

```
public Int64 addNewService(Service newService)
    {
        con = new DbConnection();
        string query = "INSERT INTO [Service] (Description) VALUES(@Description) SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT);";
        Dictionary<string, object> sqlParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        sqlParameters.Add("@Description", newService.Description);
        return con.putDataAndGetId(query, sqlParameters);
    }
```

PutDataAndGetIdMethod:

```
        public Int64 putDataAndGetId(string _query, Dictionary<string, object> sqlParameters)
    {
        _cmd = CreateSqlCommand(_query, sqlParameters);
        Int64 id;
        openConnection();
        id = (Int64)_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        closeConnection();
        return id;
    }
```

CreateSqlCommand Method :

```
 private SqlCommand CreateSqlCommand(string commandText, Dictionary<string, Object> sqlParameters)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = _con;
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        if (sqlParameters != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> item in sqlParameters)
            {
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(item.Key, item.Value);
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
        }
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        return command;
    }
```

I tried to update record as above code. But `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT);` code doesn't return the id of updated record by executing the `id = (Int64)_cmd.ExecuteScalar();` line of code.

How to use this method structure into update operations..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how do you find the record to UPDATE? To find that record you need its primary key, and this key is probably your ID. You need to know it to update anything (or some other way to UNIQUE identify your record)

Comment: I would recommend using an ORM like Entity Framework, which will handle these problems for you (in a cross database kind of way).  You could write SQL that include `RETURN last_inserted_id()` but that wouldn't work across the different kinds of SQL server (MS/MySql/Postgres etc).

Comment: As an update operation can affect multiple rows, it returns the amount of affected rows and not the id of the last updated row. You need to get your ID on a different way, either by extracting it from your parameters or by querying the row beforehand, checking that it is only one and reading the ID.

Comment: Yes when updating, I pass the ID as a parameter. But I use same method (`PutDataAndGetId`) to update and insert data. Because I cannot return the parameterized Id back, when updating. I have to select updated record id and that should be returned from `ExecuteScalar` method as well.

Comment: You can't do it in a clean way if you use the same method for UPDATE and INSERT. You need to make a distinction between those 2 types of queries as they behave differently.

Comment: In my case I update only one record at a time. No multiple records are updated. But thank you for showing me to a very tricky point. Im looking for a way to return the updated ID by piece of code like `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT)`

Comment: Do you realize that the update doesn't change the ID? The same id that you are passing in the WHERE statement?